# I need a popup on my wordpress site with a button. As i click on the button, url of the current page should get stored in a variable

Tags: wordpress

I have installed a plugin which is working but not able to get the url of the page through click on the button in popup

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on whether you are doing it via javascript or PHP. And if the popup iframe is an external URL then it wouldn't work.

Comment: I am not able to apply any kind of php and js code on the popup.... As it is saying that it can accept only html and css"

So can i have a plugin which would accept my js and php code?